# Fancybox and html content: set nav gallery only clicking the arrows rather the entire content

Tags: javascript, fancybox

I'm using fancybox(1) to render boxes (image gallery) using an html content rather single images.

I have an html with an image, title, description, metadata and a link called "click here to obtain the entire sheet".

When I click on the content (left/right) I obtain the navigation between the elements, but I want that clicking the link the browser redirects in the correct page rather in the next navigation element!

How solve?
Thank's
Vito

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED with a css trick. Not so elegant, but works

.fancybox-nav {
    height:85% !important;
}